# How to use async for callbacks using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I have search function once i have search String from clinet i want to loop through files and match the string from files in fs, I have problem in loop i want to get all match result and send result to client. Below trying to achieve but getting an error pasted in question. New to async  library any help will be appreciated.

app.js

```
app.get('/serverSearch', function (req, res) {
    var searchTxt = req.query.searchTxt;
    dirDirectory.readDirectory(function(logFiles){
        // res.json(logFiles);
        if(logFiles){
            searchFileService.readFile(searchTxt,logFiles,function(lines,err){
                        console.log('Logs',lines);
                          if (err)
                           return res.send();
                           res.json(lines);
                    })

        }
    });

    console.log('Search text', searchTxt);
});
```

service.js

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var async = require('async');
var searchStr;
var result = [];


//Async Method
function readFile(str, logFiles, callback) {
    async.series([
        //Load user to get `userId` first
        function(callback) {
            searchStr = str;
            for (var i = 0; i < logFiles.length; i++) {
                if (logFiles[i].filename !== '.gitignore') {
                    fs.readFile('logs/dit/' + logFiles[i].filename, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
                        if (err) {
                            return console.log(err);
                        }
                        inspectFile(data);
                    });
                }
                callback(result);
            }
        },
        //Load posts (won't be called before task 1's "task callback" has been called)
        function() {
            function inspectFile(data, callback) {
                var lines = data.split('\n'); // get the lines
                lines.forEach(function(line) { // for each line in lines
                    if (line.indexOf(searchStr) != -1) { // if the line contain the searchSt
                        result.push(line);
                        // then log it
                        return line;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    ], function(err) { //This function gets called after the two tasks have called their "task callbacks"
        if (err) return err;
    });
};
```

Error

```
  if (fn === null) throw new Error("Callback was already called.");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `async.map` instead of series. You are miss understanding what series does, series process request top down. You are attempting to break this chain by accessing a function within the series itself. Which is a no, no.

for example:

```
async.series([
    function() {
        let i = 0;
        do {
            console.log("I'm first in the series: ", i);
            i++;
        } while (i < 3);
        callback(); // This tells us this function has finished.
    },
    function() {
        let i = 0;
        do {
            console.log("I'm next in the series: ", i);
            i++;
        } while (i < 3);
        callback(); // This tells us this function has finished.
    }
]);
```

The output of this would be:

`I'm next in the series: 0`

`I'm next in the series: 1`

`I'm next in the series: 2`

until the callback is fired, which then tells async to move to the next function in the series array.

The output then would be:

`I'm last in the series: 0`

`I'm last in the series: 1`

`I'm last in the series: 2`

At no point in this series should you be accessing the function within the series after the current. So you should never be trying to cross access that.

With `async.map` you can actually perform on operation on each entity within your array, which is essentially what you are trying to do.

```
var results = [];
async.map(logFiles, function(logfile, callback) {
    if (logfile.filename !== '.gitignore') {
       fs.readFile('logs/dit/' + logfile.filename, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
           if (err) {
               callback(err, null);
           }
           var lines = data.split('\n'); // get the lines
           lines.forEach(function(line) { // for each line in lines
               if (line.indexOf(searchStr) != -1) { // if the line contain the searchSt
                   results.push(line);
                   callback(null, results);
               }
           });
    }
}), function(error, result) {
     results.map(result => {
         console.log(result);
     });
});
```

Also you should use util.inspect instead of console.log, it's much cleaner and has more options.

The documentation on this is a bit rough, but here it is. https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#map hope this helps!

Comment: there is some syntax issue in your code that i am trying to resolve

Comment: yea sorry, I was mixing ES6 and ES5 but it should be close to what you need. Hope it helps!

Comment: @hussain yea, that's what tells the map to continue moving forward.

Comment: got you, new to nodejs its confusing syntax error i tried to fix but its breaking on other lines if you can help to fix that i will appreciate it

Comment: getting this error after syntax issue resolved `if (fn === null) throw new Error("Callback was already called.");
                             ^

Error: Callback was already called.` its same error i was getting with my code

Comment: That error means you are calling the callbacks in more places then it should be called. If your call is a circle e.g. ( c ) -> ( c ) -> ( c ) you'd call c once in each circle. Instead you're doing ( c, c ) which is breaking. Without you actually updating your code and showing us I can't be more help sorry.

Comment: Thanks i got the understanding of callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [async.eachSeries method](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachSeries):

```
function readFile(str, logFiles, callback) {
    async.eachSeries(array, function(item, cb){
       //Process item
       cb(error,item);
    }, function(err){
       if (err) {
           console.log("Some error in one of the items");
           callback(err);
       } else {
           console.log("All arrays items have been treated successfully");
           callback(null);
       }
    });
}
```

And I would recommend to load the *user* and *posts* before using the *async.eachSeries* function.

Comment: your code is working and its printing all arrays treated successfully but its not sending results to client

Comment: @hussain What about now? I've updated the answer. I wasn't aware you also needed to resolve the callback to the client.